# My style doesn't inherits the mahapps style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, mahapps.metro

I'm using MahApps to create a Modern UI app. I want to create a style for all the GroupBoxes present in my UserControl.
To do that I wrote this code :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type GroupBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="290"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

This is well applied to my groupboxes but visibly it doesn't inherit the style defined by MahApps. I tried to add a `x:Key` and explicitly use it like that : `<GroupBox Style={StaticResource MyGroupBoxStyle} Header="Directories">` but it doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BasedOn`needs a Style as far as I know.

I'm not using MahApps but you could [inherit from the style directly](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.GroupBox.xaml):
`BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroGroupBox}`.

Comment: Having same problem, but mine is the MenuItem which have its style defined under Menu with no name so cant inherit from it directly. Any inputs on how to do it?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with this. Maybe try and assign a name, if it is still relevant?